# Spark remove Apache Orc file

Tags: apache-spark, orc

I have stored a spark data frame as orc-file using spark shell as follows:

```
    jdbcDF.write.format("orc").partitionBy("ID").save("applicationsPartitioned")
```

I found out that the data now lives in windows\system32\applicationsPartitioned

How do I properly remove the orc-file? 
I could just shut down spark and remove the directory myself, but is there some meta-data stored somewhere about this directory?

Comment: Were you running `cmd` as an administrator?

Comment: yes, if I don't then spark-shell gave a lot of errors

Comment: Change the directory before you invoke `spark-shell`. It defaults to  C:\Windows\System32\ and it's not advisable to write/remove stuff from there. You never know when it will break something. It's Windows after-all.

Comment: Thanks, this was also very helpful. I'm new to spark and still figuring it out step by step. I now made a shortcut to cmd.exe that will run as admin + automatically switch directory and start spark-shell. This way it won't be forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it manually, however you can use hadoop file system to do it.

For example:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
fs.delete(new Path(path), recursive)
```

This will make it OS and filesystem independent.

Comment: I changed "hadoopfs.delete(new Path(path), recursive)"
to "fs.delete(new Path(path))" and it worked great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think have to remove the directory manually but if you are trying to remove the directory for next output you can simply use the method `mode()` to override the existing directory

```
jdbcDF.write.format("orc")
.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
.partitionBy("ID")
.save("applicationsPartitioned")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, will probably use in future, but this time I simply want to remove it since it isn't in the right place.